# cleaning up missed geocoding (or general advise on data cleaning)

Tags: geocoding

I've got a rather large database of location addresses (500k+) from around the world. Though lots of the address are duplicates or near duplicates. 
Whenever a new address is entered, I check to see if it is in the database already, and if so, i take the already existing lat/long and apply it to the new entry.
 The reason I don't  link to a separate table is because the addresses are not used as a group to search on, and their are often enough differences in the address that i want to keep them distinct.
If I have a complete match on the address, I apply that lat/long. If not, I go to city level and apply that, if I can't get a match there, I have a separate process to run.

Now that you have the extensive background, the problem. Occasionally I end up with a lat/long that is far outside of the normal acceptable range of error. However, strangely, it is normally just one or two of these lat/longs that fall outside the range, while the rest of the data exists in the database with the correct city name.

How would you recommend cleaning up the data. I've got the geonames database, so theoretically i have the correct data. What i'm struggling with is what is the routine you would run to get this done.

If someone could point me in the direction of some (low level) data scrubbing direction, that would be great.

Comment: I don't quite understand the problem... Do you think you could clarify it a bit?

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but true principles never die, right?

I work in the address verification industry for a company called SmartyStreets. When you have a large list of addresses and need them "cleaned up", polished to official standards, and then will rely on it for any aspect of your operations, you best look into CASS-Certified software (US only; countries vary widely, and many don't offer such a service officially).

The USPS licenses CASS-Certified vendors to "scrub" or "clean up" (meaning: standardize and verify) address data. I would suggest that you look into a service such as SmartyStreets' [LiveAddress](http://www.smartystreets.com/Products/) to verify addresses or process a list all at once. There are other options, but I think this is the most flexible and affordable for you. You can scrub your initial list then use the API to validate new addresses as you receive them.

Update: I see you're using JSON for various things (I love JSON, by the way, it's so easy to use). There aren't many providers of the services you need which offer it, but SmartyStreets *does*. Further, you'll be able to educate yourself on the topic of address validation by reading some of the resources/articles on that site.